# Can i export video from "CS5 FLASH" of actions created with AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, video, export

I created animation using AS3. Actions are distributed in main timeline. I created frame event listener, which set a current frame of several MovieClips. But when I export video, AS3 isn't executed.

Comment: That's because a video is by definition not executable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video

Comment: If you want you can make a script which will create a image of each frame `BitmapData.draw ()`, and then put the images together to create video. Basicaly the video is a sequence of the images at the end ;)

Comment: I don't wanna do video executable. I wanna to create actions  with AS3, and then export as video.

Comment: I can create image with BitmapData.draw (). But, how do i save about 3000 images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export to quicktime format using actionscript driven animation in flash cs3 and above (and maybe even earlier versions, but I'm not sure). I'm not sure about other formats, but if they don't support actionscript, you can easily convert the quicktime video to something else. Just do `File->Export->Export Movie...`  and change the file format to `.mov`

Comment: @mptinklas If an answer helps you on StackOverflow, you should accept it as correct so that others who stumble on this question in the future can find the correct answer quickly. (Plus you get 2 reputation for it ;) )